# Hat "jemanden zur Rede stellen" eine andere Bedeutung als "jemanden sich rechtfertigen lassen"?

Tags: meaning, expression

Ich hatte diesen Ausdruck im Englischen [gesucht](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260974/to-take-someone-to-task-does-not-mean-to-make-someone-do-something) und *to take someone to task* gefunden. Ich bin der Meinung, dass der deutsche Ausdruck für *jemanden sich rechtfertigen zu lassen* verwendet wird.

Mit anderen Worten: Die Person, die zur Rede gestellt wird, muss sich rechtfertigen. In der Regel ist dies eine unangenehme Situation für diese Person. Im Allgemeinen ist es eine unangenehme Atmosphäre für beide Parteien.

**Gibt es eine andere Bedeutung als diese?**

Mir ist aufgefallen, dass die Übersetzung im Englischen (siehe oben) nicht ganz dem Deutschen entspricht.

Comment: Die fragwürdige Übersetzung kommt vielleicht daher, dass man in der Situation ja nicht wirklich an einer guten Rechtfertigung interessiert ist, sondern den anderen/die andere mal ordentlich zusammenstauchen will. Bei "jemanden zur Rede stellen" schwingt für mich immer so ein "egal was du sagst: Was du gemacht hast, ist nicht zu rechtfertigen" mit. Versucht der/die zur Rede Gestellte dann doch, sich zu rechtfertigen, verschlimmert das eher die Situtation, weil die/der zur Rede Stellende vielleicht eine Entschuldigung erwartet, keine Erklärung.

Comment: @Chris also ich kenne das eigentlich nur in der Bedeutung, dass man jemanden dazu auffordert, sich zu rechtfertigen, indem man ihn mit einem Vorwurf oder Ähnlichem konfrontiert. Aus meiner Sicht kann dies jedoch durchaus mit dem Ziel geschehen, einfach die Sicht des anderen zu hören. Nach dem Motto "A wirft Dir das vor, was ist aus Deiner Sicht passiert?". Es geht ja nicht immer nur um vollendete Tatsachen, sondern ggf. auch um das Einholen der Sichtweisen aller Beteiligten.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Vielleicht lebe ich einfach in einem weniger diplomatisch agierenden Umfeld.^^ Wenn ich in meinem Umfeld höre, dass jemand zur Rede gestellt wird, dann ist die Kacke meist am Dampfen. ;-)

Comment: Klar dampft die Kacke, aber den Aspekt der vorgefertigten Meinung, die nicht änderbar ist, sehe ich nicht ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rede) ist hier wieder einmal hilfreich, denn dort steht, recht deutlich formuliert: *jemanden zur Rede stellen (von jemandem Rechenschaft fordern; ursprünglich Aussage, Rechtfertigung vor Gericht)*. Es würde mich sehr wundern, wenn eine andere (belegbare) Bedeutung auftaucht.

Bzgl. des Englischen *to take someone to task* kann ich nur bestätigen, was bereits in der Antwort im englischen Forum steht. Eine kleine Hinzufügung noch, die dort nicht auftaucht: *to confront sb.* passt oft. Es geht bei solchen Redewendungen ja nie um exakte Bedeutungsentsprechungen, sondern immer nur um sich teilweise überschneidende Bedeutungsfelder, wenn man so will.

Comment: Komme mir ein bisschen doof vor. Danke. Ich hätte daran denken sollen im Duden nach zu schauen. Die Englische Übersetzung hatte mich etwas zum Straucheln gebracht.